# How to update multiple rows using a sub-query and order by in the sub-query?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to update a table using a sub-query, however the sub-query contains multiple joins as I am getting data from multiple tables, and as a business requirement I am forced to add an Order by in the sub-query to sort elements based on the primary key, if order by is not added then the output is not accurate. A simple example without the joins of what I am trying to do is:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEES e
SET (e.JOB, e.SAL, e.COMM) = 
(
SELECT p.JOB, p.SAL, p.COMM FROM EMP p WHERE p.ENAME = e.ENAME ORDER BY p.DEPTNO
)
WHERE DEPTNO = 30;
```

The main issue is not being able to use Order by in sub-query.

This throws an error message:

```
Error at line 4/80: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220100", line 847
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_220100", line 833
ORA-06512: at "APEX_220100.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 1903
```

If I remove the Order by from the sub-query then I get no error message, however my result is not the expected. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is syntactically invalid to have an `ORDER BY` clause in the outer-most sub-query of a correlated sub-query as the order of the results does not matter as there should only be a single matching row for the sub-query. Therefore the general answer to your question is that it is impossible to have an `ORDER BY` clause because the syntax forbids it.

Since Oracle 12, there is an exception which allows an `ORDER BY` clause in a correlated sub-query and that is when you also use `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY` to guarantee that the sub-query returns only a single row.

So, if you are getting multiple rows for the sub-query and you only want the first row then, from Oracle 12, you can use:

```sql
UPDATE EMPLOYEES e
SET (e.JOB, e.SAL, e.COMM) = (SELECT p.JOB, p.SAL, p.COMM
                              FROM   EMP p
                              WHERE  p.ENAME = e.ENAME
                              ORDER BY p.DEPTNO
                              FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY)
WHERE DEPTNO = 30;
```

However, it seems more likely that you would want to use something else to correlate the queries so that you only ever get a single row.

> as a business requirement I am forced to add an Order by in the sub-query to sort elements based on the primary key

This does not appear to be what you are doing as you are sorting by the department number, `DEPTNO`, and it seems to be unlikely that the primary key for an employee is the number of their department.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=86acdc3b7048dd9df6a15eef2732be8d)*